# LOOP if-simulation, need help to understand

Tags: loops, if-statement, logic

I have somehow hard time in understanding the following program in [LOOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOOP_%28programming_language%29) (you can also read the article in its original [German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOOP-Programm)), which is supposed to simulate `IF x=0 THEN A END`.

```
y:=1;
LOOP x DO y:=0 END;
LOOP y DO A END;
```

How exactly does this simulate an `IF` statement? Why can't I do this:

```
x:=0;
LOOP x DO A END;
```

Comment: What language is this for? You should add it as a tag.

Comment: this is a LOOP language, very old one, so old language that there is no tag for it in stackoverflow.. :D

Comment: Older than FORTRAN and COBOL? 'Cause SO has tags for those. In any case, the question needs a note about the language; if there's no tag, you could specify in the question that "LOOP" is the name of the programming language, and not just a reference to loops. As the language is  obscure, it could also use a link to more information.

Comment: sure, you are right. i will do it now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what this language is but if one assumes that `LOOP cntr DO stmt END;` executes `stmt` as long as `cntr` is greater than zero (and it's decremented after each iteration), then this works as follows:

`1` is assigned to `y`. If `x` is greater than zero, then `y` is assigned `0`. If `x` is zero the value of `y` remains `1`. In the next loop, `A` is executed once if `y` is `1` which is the case only if the previous `LOOP` statement didn't execute, that is if `x` was equal to `0`. The main advantage of this construct is that `A` is executed only once and not as much times as is the value of `x` if it is greater than zero which `LOOP x DO A END;` would do.

Here is the logic once again, step by step:

- `y` is set to `1`
- `y` is set to zero `x` times. This is equivalent to `IF x <> 0 THEN y:=0 END`
- `A` is executed `y` times (once if `x` is zero and zero times if `x` is non-zero)

Those three steps translate to: if `x` is zero, execute `A` once, otherwise execute `A` zero times (i.e. don't execute).

Comment: okay, so if i see it right, it will work like this:
if x>0 then set y=0 so many times as the value of x, then run A, 
if x=0, then run A directly. am i right?

Comment: If `x <> 0` then `y` would be set to `0` and the next loop would execute `A` zero times. Only if `x = 0` then `y` would retain the value of `1` and in the next loop `A` would be executed _exactly once_. So in summary, if `x = 0`, then `A` is executed exactly once. Otherwise `A` is executed zero times (i.e. not executed at all) => `IF x=0 THEN A END`

Comment: i think, if ``x<>0`` then next loop willnot execute ``A`` because the ``y=0``. only if ``x=0``, then ``y=1`` which enables the next loop to run only ``1`` - time. right?